# gcc atomic builtins and availability version

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to verify if I can use the "__atomic_exchange_n" in gcc compiler I have (version 4.3.2) and I can't find anywhere if it supports atomics, if it doesnt't can I use "__sync_lock_test_and_set"?

Where can I see if my compiler supports this functions, or when they where introduce in gcc? thanks!

pseudo-code:

```
#if defined HAVE_GCC_SYNC_BUILTINS

     #define AtomicExchange(vP, v)   (void)__sync_lock_test_and_set(vP, v)  

 #elif defined HAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS

     #define AtomicExchange(vP, v)   (void)__atomic_exchange_n(vP,v, o)

 #endif
```

---

**Edit:**

I have gcc 4.3.2 and i cannot update it. (Platform restriction)
Is there any way to o implement an atomic store of a 64bits variable?

I tried to use the "__sync_lock_test_and_set(vP, v)" as i said above and for int, short, and char it works, but for the int64(long long) i can performance the store because it gives "undefined reference to __sync_lock_test_and_set_8". The "_8" is 8bytes (64bits).

Is there anything I can do to implement  the 64bits atomic store?
thank you

Comment: What are the leading underscores before the preprocessor directives for? I assume they are not there in the real code?

Comment: Just to ident the code*

Comment: Can you tell the CPU architecture? `vendor_id` and `model name` from `/proc/cpuinfo`, or `uname -m -p`, or settings you use when cross-compiling to that architecture? Certain architectures like ARM variants have different approaches to compare-and-swap/test-and-set operations. Although all built-ins will work, some of them work better (that is, faster, with fewer iterations of internal loops when contested, and so on). I can show some example cases if I knew the architecture.

Comment: @NominalAnimal the cpu architure varies, but normally it is a powerpc 32bits, but gcc 4.3.2 says: "undefined reference to __sync_lock_test_and_set_8" for 64bits variables.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two basic approaches to atomic operations [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) (or compare-and-swap), and [LL/SC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) (or load-link/store-conditional). Their low-level differences are such that they cannot be directly exposed to userspace. The old-style __sync built-ins were based on Intel Itanium architecture which uses the CAS approach; it is no surprise it is not a terribly good match for LL/SC -style architectures' atomics. The practical result is that different C approaches (if having to use sync built-ins) work best on different architectures; the new-style atomic built-ins tend to yield better code on all architectures, being based on and having had more exposure to different kinds of architectures.

GCC 4.3.2 supports only the old-style [__sync_](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html#g_t_005f_005fsync-Builtins) built-ins. There are two general approaches to replacing a [`__atomic_exchange_n()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) operation:

```
static inline TYPE atomic_exchange(TYPE *const ptr, const TYPE newval)
{
    TYPE oldval;
    do {
        oldval = *ptr;
    } while (!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(ptr, oldval, newval));
    return oldval;
}

static inline TYPE atomic_exchange(TYPE *const ptr, const TYPE newval)
{
    TYPE oldval, tmpval;
    oldval = *ptr;
    do {
        tmpval = oldval;
        oldval = __sync_val_compare_and_swap(ptr, tmpval, newval);
    } while (oldval != tmpval);
    return oldval;
}
```

If `newval` is zero or all-ones, we can also use

```
static inline TYPE atomic_clear(TYPE *const ptr)
{
    return __sync_fetch_and_and(ptr, (TYPE)0);
}

static inline TYPE atomic_setall(TYPE *const ptr)
{
    return __sync_fetch_and_or(ptr, ~(TYPE)0);
}
```

If there are only a few processor/cache architecture targets, you can always write an inline assembly function that works, assuming the hardware actually supports 64-bit atomic operations. This would be quite easy, if you can compile a simple new-style atomic exchange function, say

```
TYPE atomic_exchange_prototype(TYPE *const ptr, const TYPE newval)
{
    return __atomic_exchange_n(ptr, newval, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
}
```

for each target architecture to assembly code (say, using `-O2 -S` gcc flags, plus architecture-specific options; or `-O2 --static -c` if a GCC-provided function is used, in which case `objdump -d` can provide the disassembly). In some cases the architecture manuals actually describe how to best construct atomic operations.

If the hardware architecture does not support 64-bit atomic operations (although I would be a bit surprised if a 32-bit architecture could not support 64-bit atomic operations at all, even via emulation), there may still be workarounds. For example, using *generation counters*. (Basically, two or more atomically incremented (small) counter fields are used to determine when data is valid. Exact implementation depends on the needs, and particularly when (from which context) the data is modified.)

Answer (score 1):

You can just google for the GCC 4.3.2 spec

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

I think you can use

```
type __sync_val_compare_and_swap (type *ptr, type oldval type newval, ...)
```

> These builtins perform an atomic compare and swap. That is, if the
>   current value of *ptr is oldval, then write newval into *ptr.
>
> The “bool” version returns true if the comparison is successful and newval
>   was written. The “val” version returns the contents of *ptr before the
>   operation.

```
type __sync_lock_test_and_set (type *ptr, type value, ...)
```

> This builtin, as described by Intel, is not a traditional test-and-set 
>   operation, but rather an atomic exchange operation. It
>   writes value into *ptr, and returns the previous contents of *ptr.
>
> Many targets have only minimal support for such locks, and do not support a full exchange operation. In this case, a target may support
>   reduced functionality here by which the only valid value to store is
>   the immediate constant 1. The exact value actually stored in *ptr is
>   implementation defined.
>
> This builtin is not a full barrier, but rather an acquire barrier. This means that references after the builtin cannot move to (or be
>   speculated to) before the builtin, but previous memory stores may not
>   be globally visible yet, and previous memory loads may not yet be
>   satisfied.

Comment: I want to use the sync_lock, I was looking at the pages of atomics and never to the url! From there i could go to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/
and check in which version they introduce the atomic builtins (4.7.4 manual!)

Thank you!